# Angular 2 - Routing Issues with file based app

Tags: angular, webpack, routes, typescript2.0

I've been tinkering with this one based on several threads and tutorials, none of which seem to solve this particular issue. I have a small app that is being loaded from the file system and not through HTTP. No matter how I tweak the set up `index.html#/character` or `index.html#character` will always route to the `AppComponent` and not the `CharacterComponent`. If I change the bootstrap in `app.module.ts` from `AppComponent` to `CharacterComponent`, it will show character. I have a feeling that I'm just missing one piece of the routing config that will correctly route between components.

#### Versions

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26",
    "ui-router-ng2": "^1.0.0-beta.3"
  }
```

#### Webpack

```
 entry: {
    'angular2': [
      'zone.js',
      'rxjs',
      'reflect-metadata',
      '@angular/core'
    ],
    'app': './app/app'
  },
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <app></app>
    </div>
    <script src="../build/common.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'templates/selectFile.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

#### templates/selectFiles.html

```
<div id="selectFile">
  <a href="" id="fileselect"></a>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

#### character.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'templates/character.html'
})

export class CharacterComponent {
}
```

#### templates/character.html

```
<div id="selectFile">
  character <br />
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

#### app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { CharacterComponent }   from './character.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'character', component: CharacterComponent },
  { path: '', component: AppComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CharacterComponent
  ],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap your app component, that will always be on the page. The router is going to put the appropriate component into the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag (actually at the same level, but that's beside the point).

The question is, where do you want the empty route `''` to go? You might have a `HomePageComponent` that gets loaded, or you might want to redirect to your `CharacterComponent` using the `redirectTo` option.

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/character',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

[Read more here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#redirect).

Comment: That took care of it. I made a base AppComponent that only has the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and then separate classes for the first and second component. I don't know how many times I read the doc for the ng router and this just didn't come through. Thanks!